# create a tag textField with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, struts2

I want to create a textfield with my button, but when i click in a button, there are no textField create. Help me

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add() {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("s:textfield");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("id", "classe");
    element.setAttribute("name","classe");
    element.setAttribute("label", "Classe");
    element.setAttribute("labelposition", "left");
}
</script>
</head>


<s:textfield name="classe" id="classe" label="Classe" labelposition="left" />

<sj:submit id="formSubmit1" value="Ajouter" button="true" onclick="add()"/>
```

Comment: `<s:textfield/>` is a server-side tag. You cannot create it via JavaScript since the JavaScript executes on the client-side, after the server has sent the response. The answers here should help you create a normal HTML text input, though.

Answer (score 2):

Your code in the add() function, creates a new element, but does not add it to the page.  You would need to use something like [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/InsertBefore) or [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) to put it in the actual page and position it in the DOM where you want it.

See this jsFiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/dEstk/

```
function add() {
    //Create an input type dynamically.
    var element = document.createElement("input");
    //Assign different attributes to the element.
    element.setAttribute("id", "classe");
    element.setAttribute("type", "text");
    document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the jquery-way:

```
function add() {
    $("<input />").attr({
       "id": "classe",
       "name": "classe",
       "label": "Classe",
       "labelposition": "left"
    }).appendTo("body");    
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You created the element but never inserted it into the DOM. You should do something like this:

```
  // add the newly created element and it's content into the DOM
  document.body.appendChild(element);
```

There are other methods you can use to add the element, like *document.body.insertBefore()*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to add is a textarea.
You can try doing it with the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function add() {
            //Create an input type dynamically.
            var element = document.createElement("textarea");
            //Assign different attributes to the element.
            element.setAttribute("id", "classe");
            element.setAttribute("name", "classe");
            element.setAttribute("label", "Classe");
            element.setAttribute("labelposition", "left");
            // With this line you add the element to <body>My Element</body>.
            document.body.appendChild(element);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add textarea"/>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```